# Frequent Timeout expired exception

Tags: asp.net, sql, timeout

Anybody please help me!

I am facing Timeout expired exception again n again in my asp.net application and this has started recently.
The strange thing is that, there is no pattern of when it starts coming.
It just starts coming and be there for sometime and then gets disappear automatically!
I am still not able to find what makes it come and what makes it disappear.

To check whether my sql server is not responding I always try to run the query in my sql server management studio and it runs there perfectly and fast.

One of the solutions I tried is to make Pooling true in my connection string and make my poo size large enough, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hanging query and your script is just expiring.  Is it PHP?  Try ini_set('max_execution_time', 300) to let it spin for 5 minutes.  If you want the script to finish quicker, you may have to figure out which query is hanging.